# require_tree argument must be a directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I want to have a onepager with different css, javascript and images files to use as my landing page for my application.

I moved my css in the vendor/assets folder under a subfolder called onepager. I used a subfolder because I'll only use these files for the onepager and not for anything else.

e.g.

```
vendor/assets/stylesheets/onepager/
```

I created a separate layout which references separate css files. > onepager.html.erb

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'onepager', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'onepager', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %
```

Within the files onepager.js and onepager.css.scss I want them to reference to the files within the vendor/assets/xxx/onepager/ folder. I have added following code but I get an error.

**onepager.css.scss**

```
/*
* This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
* listed below.
*
* Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
* or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
*
* You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
* compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any styles
* defined in the other CSS/SCSS files in this directory. It is generally better to create a new
* file per style scope.
*
*= require_tree ./onepager/
*/
```

**onepager.js**

```
/*
* This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
* listed below.
*
* Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
* or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
*
* You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
* compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any styles
* defined in the other CSS/SCSS files in this directory. It is generally better to create a new
* file per style scope.
*
*= require_tree ./onepager/
*/
```

I get the error that the require tree is not a directory? This is strange since it is a directory and I assume the files within the vendor assets are loaded automatically?

How can I fix this?

> require_tree argument must be a directory
>         (in /home/ubuntu/workspace/app/assets/stylesheets/onepager.css.scss:13)

Comment: You tagged this with `ruby-on-rails`, `ruby-on-rails-3` and `ruby-on-rails-4`. Which version are you using. Please fix your tags.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the answer myself.

I have to add:

```
//= require_tree ../../../vendor/assets/javascripts/onepager
```

and the same for the css files. After that the error page notifies me to update the config/initializers/assets.rb file with the code it provides.

I now works.

Source: 
https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/1223

Comment: Glad you found a solution! After reviewing your code again it seems clear. Didn't do enough research, deleting my question. Btw, wouldn't you prefer having the code to onepager in the assets directory, since its *your* code?

Comment: AFAICS, the Rails documentation, as well as the assets_path, suggest it should be possible to access things in `vendor/assets` as if they were in `app/assets`. But I also needed this relative path. Does anyone know whether the documentation is wrong or maybe our configuration is wrong or ... (Rails 5.0.1).